# How to make or add options for packages or functions

Tags: formatting, color, package-writing, package-options

I'm using at this moment the [Piano Package](http://ctan.org/pkg/piano). This Package is a little limited so I want to change a few things.
The standard color of the dots is orange. I want to change this in different situations. But I don't want to edit the `sty` file every time.
I want to change the options prefered in

```
\keyboard[color = … ]…
```

or

```
\usepackage[color = … ]{piano}
```

How can I change this?
The first option is my prefered option but the standard code is "`\keyboard[Dso][Fso][Aso][Dst]`"
So i hav to change this to `\keyboard{Dso}{Fso}{Aso}{Dst}` and I don't know if this is possible… 
can anybody help me?
Thanks

Comment: Sorry but I really don't understand your question. It sounds as if you'd like to type `\keyboard{Dso}{Fso}{Aso}{Dst}` rather than `\keyboard[Dso][Fso][Aso][Dst]` (curly brackets vs. square brackets) but I don't know (1) why you would want to do that, or (2) how that is meant to help provide greater flexibility. Posting a Minimum (non-)Working Example (i.e. minimal but complete code) should help you make your question clearer and encourage people to help.

Comment: You can't change the package options without having to edit the `.sty` file. It is sometimes more feasible to patch existing commands to suit your needs, or to write user-level interface macros that support your needs (like switching colour, say).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With the following redefinition of `\keyboard` now you have an optional first argument delimited by parentheses, allowing you to change the color at will:

So, for example, now you can say:

```
\keyboard[Co][Eo][Gso][Ct][Et]

\keyboard(cyan)[Co][Eo][Gso][Ct][Et]

\keyboard(olive)[Co][Eo][Gso][Ct][Et]
```

The code:

```
\documentclass[11pts]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{piano}
\usepackage{xparse}

\makeatletter
\RenewDocumentCommand{\keyboard}{D(){orange}O{0}O{0}O{0}O{0}O{0}O{0}O{0}}{

%% Clavier 2 octaves
\setlength{\unitlength}{0.5cm}
\begin{picture}(15,4.5)
%Touches blanches
\multiput(0,0)(1,0){14}%
{\line(0,1){4}}

%Contour
\put(0,0){\line(0,1){4}}
\put(0,0){\line(1,0){14}}
\put(14,0){\line(0,1){4}}
\put(0,4){\line(1,0){14}}

%Touches noires
\linethickness{3mm}
\multiput(1,4)(1,0){2}%
{\line(0,-1){3}}

\multiput(4,4)(1,0){3}%
{\line(0,-1){3}}

\linethickness{3mm}
\multiput(8,4)(1,0){2}%
{\line(0,-1){3}}

\multiput(11,4)(1,0){3}%
{\line(0,-1){3}}

%Rond de note
{\color{#1}

\ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{Co}}{\put(0.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
 \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{Do}}{\put(1.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{Eo}}{\put(2.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
   \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{Fo}}{\put(3.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{Go}}{\put(4.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
     \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{Ao}}{\put(5.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
      \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{Bo}}{\put(6.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
       \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{Ct}}{\put(7.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{ 
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{Dt}}{\put(8.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
         \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{Et}}{\put(9.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
          \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{Ft}}{\put(10.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
           \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{Gt}}{\put(11.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
            \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{At}}{\put(12.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
             \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{Bt}}{\put(13.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
              \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{Cso}}{\put(1,1.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
               \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{Dso}}{\put(2,1.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
                \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{Fso}}{\put(4,1.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
                 \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{Gso}}{\put(5,1.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
                  \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{Aso}}{\put(6,1.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
                   \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{Cst}}{\put(8,1.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
                    \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{Dst}}{\put(9,1.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
                     \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{Fst}}{\put(11,1.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
                      \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{Gst}}{\put(12,1.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
                       \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{Ast}}{\put(13,1.5){\circle*{0.5}}}}{}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}

\ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{Co}}{\put(0.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
 \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{Do}}{\put(1.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{Eo}}{\put(2.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
   \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{Fo}}{\put(3.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{Go}}{\put(4.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
     \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{Ao}}{\put(5.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
      \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{Bo}}{\put(6.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
       \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{Ct}}{\put(7.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{ 
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{Dt}}{\put(8.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
         \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{Et}}{\put(9.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
          \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{Ft}}{\put(10.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
           \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{Gt}}{\put(11.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
            \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{At}}{\put(12.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
             \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{Bt}}{\put(13.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
              \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{Cso}}{\put(1,1.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
               \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{Dso}}{\put(2,1.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
                \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{Fso}}{\put(4,1.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
                 \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{Gso}}{\put(5,1.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
                  \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{Aso}}{\put(6,1.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
                   \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{Cst}}{\put(8,1.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
                    \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{Dst}}{\put(9,1.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
                     \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{Fst}}{\put(11,1.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
                      \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{Gst}}{\put(12,1.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
                       \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{Ast}}{\put(13,1.5){\circle*{0.5}}}}{}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}

\ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{Co}}{\put(0.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
 \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{Do}}{\put(1.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{Eo}}{\put(2.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
   \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{Fo}}{\put(3.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{Go}}{\put(4.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
     \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{Ao}}{\put(5.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
      \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{Bo}}{\put(6.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
       \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{Ct}}{\put(7.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{ 
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{Dt}}{\put(8.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
         \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{Et}}{\put(9.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
          \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{Ft}}{\put(10.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
           \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{Gt}}{\put(11.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
            \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{At}}{\put(12.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
             \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{Bt}}{\put(13.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
              \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{Cso}}{\put(1,1.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
               \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{Dso}}{\put(2,1.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
                \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{Fso}}{\put(4,1.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
                 \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{Gso}}{\put(5,1.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
                  \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{Aso}}{\put(6,1.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
                   \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{Cst}}{\put(8,1.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
                    \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{Dst}}{\put(9,1.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
                     \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{Fst}}{\put(11,1.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
                      \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{Gst}}{\put(12,1.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
                       \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{Ast}}{\put(13,1.5){\circle*{0.5}}}}{}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}

\ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{Co}}{\put(0.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
 \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{Do}}{\put(1.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{Eo}}{\put(2.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
   \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{Fo}}{\put(3.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{Go}}{\put(4.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
     \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{Ao}}{\put(5.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
      \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{Bo}}{\put(6.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
       \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{Ct}}{\put(7.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{ 
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{Dt}}{\put(8.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
         \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{Et}}{\put(9.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
          \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{Ft}}{\put(10.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
           \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{Gt}}{\put(11.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
            \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{At}}{\put(12.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
             \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{Bt}}{\put(13.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
              \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{Cso}}{\put(1,1.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
               \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{Dso}}{\put(2,1.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
                \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{Fso}}{\put(4,1.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
                 \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{Gso}}{\put(5,1.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
                  \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{Aso}}{\put(6,1.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
                   \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{Cst}}{\put(8,1.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
                    \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{Dst}}{\put(9,1.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
                     \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{Fst}}{\put(11,1.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
                      \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{Gst}}{\put(12,1.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
                       \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{Ast}}{\put(13,1.5){\circle*{0.5}}}}{}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}

\ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{Co}}{\put(0.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
 \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{Do}}{\put(1.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{Eo}}{\put(2.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
   \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{Fo}}{\put(3.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{Go}}{\put(4.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
     \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{Ao}}{\put(5.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
      \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{Bo}}{\put(6.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
       \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{Ct}}{\put(7.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{ 
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{Dt}}{\put(8.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
         \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{Et}}{\put(9.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
          \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{Ft}}{\put(10.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
           \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{Gt}}{\put(11.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
            \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{At}}{\put(12.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
             \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{Bt}}{\put(13.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
              \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{Cso}}{\put(1,1.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
               \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{Dso}}{\put(2,1.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
                \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{Fso}}{\put(4,1.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
                 \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{Gso}}{\put(5,1.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
                  \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{Aso}}{\put(6,1.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
                   \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{Cst}}{\put(8,1.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
                    \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{Dst}}{\put(9,1.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
                     \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{Fst}}{\put(11,1.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
                      \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{Gst}}{\put(12,1.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
                       \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{Ast}}{\put(13,1.5){\circle*{0.5}}}}{}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}

\ifthenelse{\equal{#7}{Co}}{\put(0.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
 \ifthenelse{\equal{#7}{Do}}{\put(1.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#7}{Eo}}{\put(2.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
   \ifthenelse{\equal{#7}{Fo}}{\put(3.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#7}{Go}}{\put(4.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
     \ifthenelse{\equal{#7}{Ao}}{\put(5.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
      \ifthenelse{\equal{#7}{Bo}}{\put(6.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
       \ifthenelse{\equal{#7}{Ct}}{\put(7.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{ 
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#7}{Dt}}{\put(8.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
         \ifthenelse{\equal{#7}{Et}}{\put(9.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
          \ifthenelse{\equal{#7}{Ft}}{\put(10.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
           \ifthenelse{\equal{#7}{Gt}}{\put(11.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
            \ifthenelse{\equal{#7}{At}}{\put(12.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
             \ifthenelse{\equal{#7}{Bt}}{\put(13.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
              \ifthenelse{\equal{#7}{Cso}}{\put(1,1.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
               \ifthenelse{\equal{#7}{Dso}}{\put(2,1.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
                \ifthenelse{\equal{#7}{Fso}}{\put(4,1.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
                 \ifthenelse{\equal{#7}{Gso}}{\put(5,1.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
                  \ifthenelse{\equal{#7}{Aso}}{\put(6,1.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
                   \ifthenelse{\equal{#7}{Cst}}{\put(8,1.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
                    \ifthenelse{\equal{#7}{Dst}}{\put(9,1.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
                     \ifthenelse{\equal{#7}{Fst}}{\put(11,1.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
                      \ifthenelse{\equal{#7}{Gst}}{\put(12,1.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
                       \ifthenelse{\equal{#7}{Ast}}{\put(13,1.5){\circle*{0.5}}}}{}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}

\ifthenelse{\equal{#8}{Co}}{\put(0.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
 \ifthenelse{\equal{#8}{Do}}{\put(1.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#8}{Eo}}{\put(2.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
   \ifthenelse{\equal{#8}{Fo}}{\put(3.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#8}{Go}}{\put(4.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
     \ifthenelse{\equal{#8}{Ao}}{\put(5.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
      \ifthenelse{\equal{#8}{Bo}}{\put(6.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
       \ifthenelse{\equal{#8}{Ct}}{\put(7.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{ 
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#8}{Dt}}{\put(8.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
         \ifthenelse{\equal{#8}{Et}}{\put(9.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
          \ifthenelse{\equal{#8}{Ft}}{\put(10.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
           \ifthenelse{\equal{#8}{Gt}}{\put(11.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
            \ifthenelse{\equal{#8}{At}}{\put(12.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
             \ifthenelse{\equal{#8}{Bt}}{\put(13.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
              \ifthenelse{\equal{#8}{Cso}}{\put(1,1.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
               \ifthenelse{\equal{#8}{Dso}}{\put(2,1.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
                \ifthenelse{\equal{#8}{Fso}}{\put(4,1.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
                 \ifthenelse{\equal{#8}{Gso}}{\put(5,1.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
                  \ifthenelse{\equal{#8}{Aso}}{\put(6,1.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
                   \ifthenelse{\equal{#8}{Cst}}{\put(8,1.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
                    \ifthenelse{\equal{#8}{Dst}}{\put(9,1.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
                     \ifthenelse{\equal{#8}{Fst}}{\put(11,1.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
                      \ifthenelse{\equal{#8}{Gst}}{\put(12,1.5){\circle*{0.5}}}{
                       \ifthenelse{\equal{#8}{Ast}}{\put(13,1.5){\circle*{0.5}}}}{}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}
}


\end{picture}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\keyboard[Co][Eo][Gso][Ct][Et]

\keyboard(cyan)[Co][Eo][Gso][Ct][Et]

\keyboard(olive)[Co][Eo][Gso][Ct][Et]

\end{document}
```

The output:

[image: keyboard example]

Comment: Much more elegant than my solution!

Comment: That series of `\ifthenelse` is incredibly complicated and should be defined once with an auxiliary macro. Of course, loading `piano` is useless.

Comment: @egreg  it is, indeed!

Answer (score 9):

Changing the way the arguments are input is not recommendable, the square bracket notation is better since the seven arguments are optional.

For changing the color the simplest way is to load `xcolor` and change the definition of `orange`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{piano}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\colorlet{orange}{red!20}
\begin{document}
  \keyboard[Co][Eo][Gso][Ct][Et]
\end{document}
```

The `\colorlet` command acts locally, so you can change the color in some environment or group in order not to clobber the default color.

[image]

---

### Alternative version

Save the following file as `xpiano.sty`

```
\ProvidesPackage{xpiano}[2014/02/24 from piano.sty by Émile Daneault]
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xparse}

\definecolor{pianodefault}{RGB}{255,127,0}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\keyboard}{ m }
 {
  \piano_keyboard:n { #1 }
 }

\keys_define:nn { piano }
 {
  color .tl_set:N = \l_piano_color_tl,
  one   .tl_set:N = \l_piano_one_tl,
  two   .tl_set:N = \l_piano_two_tl,
  three .tl_set:N = \l_piano_three_tl,
  four  .tl_set:N = \l_piano_four_tl,
  five  .tl_set:N = \l_piano_five_tl,
  six   .tl_set:N = \l_piano_six_tl,
  seven .tl_set:N = \l_piano_seven_tl,
  color .initial:n = {pianodefault},
  one   .initial:n = {},
  two   .initial:n = {},
  three .initial:n = {},
  four  .initial:n = {},
  five  .initial:n = {},
  six   .initial:n = {},
  seven .initial:n = {},
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \piano_keyboard:n #1
 {
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn { piano } { #1 }
  %% Clavier 2 octaves
  \setlength{\unitlength}{0.5cm}
  \begin{picture}(15,4.5)
  %Touches blanches
  \multiput(0,0)(1,0){14}{\line(0,1){4}}

  %Contour
  \put(0,0){\line(0,1){4}}
  \put(0,0){\line(1,0){14}}
  \put(14,0){\line(0,1){4}}
  \put(0,4){\line(1,0){14}}

  %Touches noires
  \linethickness{3mm}
  \multiput(1,4)(1,0){2}{\line(0,-1){3}}
  \multiput(4,4)(1,0){3}{\line(0,-1){3}}
  \multiput(8,4)(1,0){2}{\line(0,-1){3}}
  \multiput(11,4)(1,0){3}{\line(0,-1){3}}
  %Rond de note
  \color{\l_piano_color_tl}
  \__piano_do_key:N \l_piano_one_tl
  \__piano_do_key:N \l_piano_two_tl
  \__piano_do_key:N \l_piano_three_tl
  \__piano_do_key:N \l_piano_four_tl
  \__piano_do_key:N \l_piano_five_tl
  \__piano_do_key:N \l_piano_six_tl
  \__piano_do_key:N \l_piano_seven_tl

  \end{picture}
  \group_end:
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__piano_do_key:N #1
 {
  \str_case:Vn #1
   {
    {}{}% initial case
    {Co}{\put(0.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}
    {Do}{\put(1.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}
    {Eo}{\put(2.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}
    {Fo}{\put(3.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}
    {Go}{\put(4.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}
    {Ao}{\put(5.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}
    {Bo}{\put(6.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}
    {Ct}{\put(7.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}
    {Dt}{\put(8.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}
    {Et}{\put(9.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}
    {Ft}{\put(10.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}
    {Gt}{\put(11.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}
    {At}{\put(12.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}
    {Bt}{\put(13.5,0.5){\circle*{0.5}}}
    {Cso}{\put(1,1.5){\circle*{0.5}}}
    {Dso}{\put(2,1.5){\circle*{0.5}}}
    {Fso}{\put(4,1.5){\circle*{0.5}}}
    {Gso}{\put(5,1.5){\circle*{0.5}}}
    {Aso}{\put(6,1.5){\circle*{0.5}}}
    {Cst}{\put(8,1.5){\circle*{0.5}}}
    {Dst}{\put(9,1.5){\circle*{0.5}}}
    {Fst}{\put(11,1.5){\circle*{0.5}}}
    {Gst}{\put(12,1.5){\circle*{0.5}}}
    {Ast}{\put(13,1.5){\circle*{0.5}}}
   }
 }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_case:nn { V }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Now you can input your keyboards with a key-value syntax:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xpiano}
\begin{document}
\keyboard{
  color=red!20,
  one=Co,
  two=Eo,
  three=Gso,
  four=Ct,
  five=Et
}

\bigskip

\keyboard{
  one=Cso,
  two=Fso,
}

\end{document}
```

The allowed keys are `color` for setting a color and `one` `two` `three` `four` `five` `six` `seven` for marking the keys; the value to `color` must be a color name in the syntax of `xcolor`, either predefined or given as a tint like in the example.

You can also globally changing the default color by redefining `pianodefault`, say

```
\definecolor{pianodefault}{RGB}{255,0,0}
```

or

```
\colorlet{pianodefault}{red}
```

for having red as the default color.

Answer (score 4):

The `piano.sty` package defines the colour `orange` for all the dots.  If you redefine the colour `orange`, you can change the appearance of each keyboard you insert.  I'm not sure how you would change the colour for each individual dot though...

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{piano}

\begin{document}

% red dots
\definecolor{orange}{RGB}{255,0,0}
\keyboard[Co][Eo][Gso][Ct][Et]

% green dots
\definecolor{orange}{RGB}{0,127,0}
\keyboard[Co][Eo][Gso][Ct][Et]

% blue dots
\definecolor{orange}{RGB}{0,0,255}
\keyboard[Co][Eo][Gso][Ct][Et]

\end{document}
```

[image]