# Edit the piano.sty to fit numbers in circles

Tags: graphics

The basis for my question: [How to make or add options for packages or functions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/162184/64781)

Is it possible to make it so that one could write numbers in the circles, like so?:

[image: example]

Here is a minimal example showing the above *without* the numbering:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{piano}
\begin{document}

\keyboard[Co][Eo][Gso][Ct][Et]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you provide the community with something that replicates the output *without* the numbers - a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)? That'll give a good foundation to start from, rather than creating something from scratch.

Comment: This is certainly possible, but looking at piano.sty, it seems you'd have to more or less completely redefine the `\keyboard` command.  A relatively simple regex would do it, but you'd need the altered piano.sty in your TeX tree.  Change the name while you're at it, to comply with the license.

Comment: Added the mwe from the readme provided in the link. I'm at a complete loss at what to do. Helpz!

Comment: I have a modified `piano.sty` and maybe it's possible to add the numbers. Can you tell how they should be defined? Are they just in sequence from the left?

Comment: I have one that adds the numbers in sequence from the left, but they're not centered because I don't really get the `picture` environment.

Comment: I really only need it to go from 0(C)-11(B), chromatically (if you've heard of pitch class, thats the thing) and then repeat from 0 when it hits C again.. When I type in the pitches I need, the corresponding keys will have a circle with a number in them. This is used for analysis stuff, and i wanted to visualize what [048] looks like.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's a modified version of `piano.sty` that adds also the function you ask for.

Also the syntax is changed, but I believe it's better than adding a bunch of optional arguments.

### `xpiano.sty`

```
\ProvidesPackage{xpiano}[2015/05/21 from piano.sty by Émile Daneault]
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xparse}

\definecolor{pianodefault}{RGB}{255,127,0}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\keyboard}{ m }
 {
  \piano_keyboard:n { #1 }
 }

\keys_define:nn { piano }
 {
  numbers .bool_set:N = \l_piano_numbers_bool,
  color   .tl_set:N  = \l_piano_color_tl,
  one     .tl_set:N  = \l_piano_one_tl,
  two     .tl_set:N  = \l_piano_two_tl,
  three   .tl_set:N  = \l_piano_three_tl,
  four    .tl_set:N  = \l_piano_four_tl,
  five    .tl_set:N  = \l_piano_five_tl,
  six     .tl_set:N  = \l_piano_six_tl,
  seven   .tl_set:N  = \l_piano_seven_tl,
  numbers .initial:n = false,
  color   .initial:n = {pianodefault},
  one     .initial:n = {},
  two     .initial:n = {},
  three   .initial:n = {},
  four    .initial:n = {},
  five    .initial:n = {},
  six     .initial:n = {},
  seven   .initial:n = {},
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \piano_keyboard:n #1
 {
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn { piano } { #1 }
  %% Clavier 2 octaves
  \setlength{\unitlength}{0.5cm}
  \begin{picture}(15,4.5)
  %Touches blanches
  \multiput(0,0)(1,0){14}{\line(0,1){4}}

  %Contour
  \put(0,0){\line(0,1){4}}
  \put(0,0){\line(1,0){14}}
  \put(14,0){\line(0,1){4}}
  \put(0,4){\line(1,0){14}}

  %Touches noires
  \linethickness{3mm}
  \multiput(1,4)(1,0){2}{\line(0,-1){3}}
  \multiput(4,4)(1,0){3}{\line(0,-1){3}}
  \multiput(8,4)(1,0){2}{\line(0,-1){3}}
  \multiput(11,4)(1,0){3}{\line(0,-1){3}}
  %Rond de note
  \color{\l_piano_color_tl}
  \__piano_do_key:N \l_piano_one_tl
  \__piano_do_key:N \l_piano_two_tl
  \__piano_do_key:N \l_piano_three_tl
  \__piano_do_key:N \l_piano_four_tl
  \__piano_do_key:N \l_piano_five_tl
  \__piano_do_key:N \l_piano_six_tl
  \__piano_do_key:N \l_piano_seven_tl

  \end{picture}
  \group_end:
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__piano_add_note:nn #1 #2
 {
  \put(#2){\circle*{0.5}}
  \bool_if:NT \l_piano_numbers_bool
   {
    \put(#2){\makebox(0,0){\color{black}\tiny#1}}
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__piano_do_key:N #1
 {
  \str_case:Vn #1
   {
    {}{}% initial case
    {Co}{\__piano_add_note:nn {0}{0.5,0.5}}
    {Do}{\__piano_add_note:nn {2}{1.5,0.5}}
    {Eo}{\__piano_add_note:nn {4}{2.5,0.5}}
    {Fo}{\__piano_add_note:nn {5}{3.5,0.5}}
    {Go}{\__piano_add_note:nn {7}{4.5,0.5}}
    {Ao}{\__piano_add_note:nn {9}{5.5,0.5}}
    {Bo}{\__piano_add_note:nn {11}{6.5,0.5}}
    {Ct}{\__piano_add_note:nn {0}{7.5,0.5}}
    {Dt}{\__piano_add_note:nn {2}{8.5,0.5}}
    {Et}{\__piano_add_note:nn {4}{9.5,0.5}}
    {Ft}{\__piano_add_note:nn {5}{10.5,0.5}}
    {Gt}{\__piano_add_note:nn {7}{11.5,0.5}}
    {At}{\__piano_add_note:nn {9}{12.5,0.5}}
    {Bt}{\__piano_add_note:nn {11}{13.5,0.5}}
    {Cso}{\__piano_add_note:nn {1}{1,1.5}}
    {Dso}{\__piano_add_note:nn {3}{2,1.5}}
    {Fso}{\__piano_add_note:nn {6}{4,1.5}}
    {Gso}{\__piano_add_note:nn {8}{5,1.5}}
    {Aso}{\__piano_add_note:nn {10}{6,1.5}}
    {Cst}{\__piano_add_note:nn {1}{8,1.5}}
    {Dst}{\__piano_add_note:nn {3}{9,1.5}}
    {Fst}{\__piano_add_note:nn {6}{11,1.5}}
    {Gst}{\__piano_add_note:nn {8}{12,1.5}}
    {Ast}{\__piano_add_note:nn {10}{13,1.5}}
   }
 }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_case:nn { V }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

### Test file

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xpiano}

\definecolor{pianoyellow}{RGB}{127,127,0}

\begin{document}
\keyboard{
  numbers,
  color=red!20,
  one=Co,
  two=Eo,
  three=Gso,
  four=Bo,
  five=Ct
}

\bigskip

\keyboard{
  color=red!20,
  one=Co,
  two=Eo,
  three=Gso,
  four=Bo,
  five=Ct
}

\bigskip

\keyboard{
  one=Cso,
  two=Fso,
}

\bigskip

\keyboard{
  color=pianoyellow,
  one=Cso,
  two=Fso,
}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

---

## Extended version

The keys `font`, `size` and `single` have been added. The default of `size` is 0.5cm (like in the original). The default for `font` is `\tiny`. With `single` one specifies a single octave (from C to B).

Also `ext` can be used, which adds an additional C at the far right, but which is probably only meaningful together with `single`, as there's no name for that note with double octave (it could be added, though).

Finally `height` can be set; the default value is 4, that is, four times the width of the keys.

In this version, instead of 10 and 11 for B flat and B, *t* and *e* are produced. A command `\keyboardsetup` allows to set the values of the parameters not related to producing notes (respecting grouping). So you can set in the preamble something like

```
\keyboardsetup{
  single,
  size=2cm,
  numbers
}
```

and all `\keyboard` commands will use those values and it won't be necessary to specify them.

### `xpiano.sty`

```
\ProvidesPackage{xpiano}[2015/05/21 from piano.sty by Émile Daneault]
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{xparse}

\definecolor{pianodefault}{RGB}{255,127,0}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\keyboard}{ m }
 {
  \piano_keyboard:n { #1 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\keyboardsetup}{ m }
 {
  \keys_set:nn { piano } { #1 }
 }

\keys_define:nn { piano }
 {
  font    .tl_set:N   = \l_piano_fontsize_tl,
  single  .bool_set:N = \l_piano_single_bool,
  ext     .bool_set:N = \l_piano_ext_bool,
  size    .dim_set:N  = \l_piano_size_dim,
  height  .tl_set:N   = \l_piano_height_tl,
  numbers .bool_set:N = \l_piano_numbers_bool,
  color   .tl_set:N   = \l_piano_color_tl,
  one     .tl_set:N   = \l_piano_one_tl,
  two     .tl_set:N   = \l_piano_two_tl,
  three   .tl_set:N   = \l_piano_three_tl,
  four    .tl_set:N   = \l_piano_four_tl,
  five    .tl_set:N   = \l_piano_five_tl,
  six     .tl_set:N   = \l_piano_six_tl,
  seven   .tl_set:N   = \l_piano_seven_tl,
  font    .initial:n  = \tiny,
  single  .initial:n  = false,
  single  .default:n  = true,
  ext     .initial:n  = false,
  ext     .default:n  = true,
  size    .initial:n  = 0.5cm,
  height  .initial:n  = 4,
  numbers .initial:n  = false,
  numbers .default:n  = true,
  color   .initial:n  = {pianodefault},
  one     .initial:n  = {},
  two     .initial:n  = {},
  three   .initial:n  = {},
  four    .initial:n  = {},
  five    .initial:n  = {},
  six     .initial:n  = {},
  seven   .initial:n  = {},
 }

\tl_new:N \l__piano_width_tl

\cs_new_protected:Npn \piano_keyboard:n #1
 {
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn { piano } { #1 }
  \bool_if:NTF \l_piano_ext_bool
   {
    \tl_set:Nx \l__piano_width_tl
     {
      \bool_if:NTF \l_piano_single_bool { 8 } { 15 }
     }
   }
   {
    \tl_set:Nx \l__piano_width_tl
     {
      \bool_if:NTF \l_piano_single_bool { 7 } { 14 }
     }
   }

  %% Clavier 2 octaves
  \setlength{\unitlength}{\l_piano_size_dim}
  \begin{picture}(\l__piano_width_tl,\l_piano_height_tl)
  %Touches blanches
  \multiput(0,0)(1,0){\l__piano_width_tl}{\line(0,1){\l_piano_height_tl}}

  %Contour
  \put(0,0){\line(0,1){\l_piano_height_tl}}
  \put(0,0){\line(1,0){\l__piano_width_tl}}
  \put(\l__piano_width_tl,0){\line(0,1){\l_piano_height_tl}}
  \put(0,\l_piano_height_tl){\line(1,0){\l__piano_width_tl}}

  %Touches noires
  \linethickness{.6\l_piano_size_dim}
  \multiput(1,\l_piano_height_tl)(1,0){2}{\line(0,-1){\fp_eval:n {0.67*\l_piano_height_tl}}}
  \multiput(4,\l_piano_height_tl)(1,0){3}{\line(0,-1){\fp_eval:n {0.67*\l_piano_height_tl}}}
  \bool_if:NF \l_piano_single_bool
   {
    \multiput(8,\l_piano_height_tl)(1,0){2}{\line(0,-1){\fp_eval:n {0.67*\l_piano_height_tl}}}
    \multiput(11,\l_piano_height_tl)(1,0){3}{\line(0,-1){\fp_eval:n {0.67*\l_piano_height_tl}}}
   }
  %Rond de note
  \color{\l_piano_color_tl}
  \__piano_do_key:N \l_piano_one_tl
  \__piano_do_key:N \l_piano_two_tl
  \__piano_do_key:N \l_piano_three_tl
  \__piano_do_key:N \l_piano_four_tl
  \__piano_do_key:N \l_piano_five_tl
  \__piano_do_key:N \l_piano_six_tl
  \__piano_do_key:N \l_piano_seven_tl

  \end{picture}
  \group_end:
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__piano_add_note:nn #1 #2
 {
  \put(#2){\circle*{0.5}}
  \bool_if:NT \l_piano_numbers_bool
   {
    \put(#2){\makebox(0,0){\color{black}\l_piano_fontsize_tl #1}}
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__piano_do_key:N #1
 {
  \str_case:Vn #1
   {
    {}{}% initial case
    {Co}{\__piano_add_note:nn {0}{0.5,0.5}}
    {Do}{\__piano_add_note:nn {2}{1.5,0.5}}
    {Eo}{\__piano_add_note:nn {4}{2.5,0.5}}
    {Fo}{\__piano_add_note:nn {5}{3.5,0.5}}
    {Go}{\__piano_add_note:nn {7}{4.5,0.5}}
    {Ao}{\__piano_add_note:nn {9}{5.5,0.5}}
    {Bo}{\__piano_add_note:nn {$e$}{6.5,0.5}}
    {Ct}{\__piano_add_note:nn {0}{7.5,0.5}}
    {Dt}{\__piano_add_note:nn {2}{8.5,0.5}}
    {Et}{\__piano_add_note:nn {4}{9.5,0.5}}
    {Ft}{\__piano_add_note:nn {5}{10.5,0.5}}
    {Gt}{\__piano_add_note:nn {7}{11.5,0.5}}
    {At}{\__piano_add_note:nn {9}{12.5,0.5}}
    {Bt}{\__piano_add_note:nn {$e$}{13.5,0.5}}
    {Cso}{\__piano_add_note:nn {1}{1,\fp_eval:n {0.5+0.33*\l_piano_height_tl}}}
    {Dso}{\__piano_add_note:nn {3}{2,\fp_eval:n {0.5+0.33*\l_piano_height_tl}}}
    {Fso}{\__piano_add_note:nn {6}{4,\fp_eval:n {0.5+0.33*\l_piano_height_tl}}}
    {Gso}{\__piano_add_note:nn {8}{5,\fp_eval:n {0.5+0.33*\l_piano_height_tl}}}
    {Aso}{\__piano_add_note:nn {$t$}{6,\fp_eval:n {0.5+0.33*\l_piano_height_tl}}}
    {Cst}{\__piano_add_note:nn {1}{8,\fp_eval:n {0.5+0.33*\l_piano_height_tl}}}
    {Dst}{\__piano_add_note:nn {3}{9,\fp_eval:n {0.5+0.33*\l_piano_height_tl}}}
    {Fst}{\__piano_add_note:nn {6}{11,\fp_eval:n {0.5+0.33*\l_piano_height_tl}}}
    {Gst}{\__piano_add_note:nn {8}{12,\fp_eval:n {0.5+0.33*\l_piano_height_tl}}}
    {Ast}{\__piano_add_note:nn {$t$}{13,\fp_eval:n {0.5+0.33*\l_piano_height_tl}}}
   }
 }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_case:nn { V }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

### Test file

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xpiano}

\definecolor{pianoyellow}{RGB}{127,127,0}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\unitlength}{2pt}

\keyboard{
  numbers,
  height=3,
  color=red!20,
  one=Co,
  two=Eo,
  three=Gso,
  four=Bo,
  five=Ct
}

\bigskip

\keyboard{
  ext,
  color=red!20,
  one=Co,
  two=Eo,
  three=Gso,
  four=Bo,
  five=Ct
}

\bigskip

\keyboard{
  single,
  ext,
  height=3,
  numbers,
  font=\small,
  size=1cm,
  one=Cso,
  two=Fso,
  three=Aso,
  four=Ct,
}

\bigskip

\keyboard{
  color=pianoyellow,
  one=Cso,
  two=Fso,
}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Brilliant! Is it possible to adjust it so C=0?

Comment: @Buschmann I'm not sure to understand. What should the number represent?

Comment: When using the pitch class analysis, C=0, Ciss=1 etc, all the way to Bb=10(or T, if one where to be presise) and B=11(E). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitch_class

Comment: @Buschmann Now it should be what you're asking for.

Comment: Thank you so much! And now, for the encore *drum roll* is it possible to adjust the size of the thing? Or, make it just one octave?

Comment: @Buschmann I hope it's from C to B. `;-)`

Comment: @Buschmann Now there's also the `ext` key that adds a final C (both with `single` and double octave). I have also fixed the width and height of the picture.

Comment: Very nice. You are a miracle worker. If i where to be picky: is it possible to add 10=t and 11=e? Which parameter adjusts the overall hight? The keys are a bit long.

Comment: @Buschmann Will this come to an end? `;-)` Try it now.

Comment: egreg, you just wrote an entire package as an answer.  You, sir, officially win at StackExchange.

Comment: @egreg (http://i.imgur.com/bgZ29GC.png) Fantastic! You have made the life for a poor musicologist much easier. Now, publish the damn thing to CTAN!

Comment: @Buschmann The package is under working; expect some changes in the syntax: it will be `\keyboard[<options>]{<notes>}`, where `<notes>` is a comma separated list of notes. It's easier and more logical.

Comment: Sounds very good. If this is to evolve to the ultimate piano tool, a couple of suggestions: 1) One should clean up the notation syntax; C, Ciss. C', Ciss'. That is "the more common" way. 2) There should be possible to use at least ten notes. 3) There should be two colors as default making it possible to use the keyboard to show piano voicings, left and right hand. Ergo there should be another { } to notate this: {C,Ciss}{C',Ciss'}.

Comment: @Buschmann About the notation for the notes I don't agree: that looks very German to me. However, it's quite easy to add different styles of notation. For the left and right hand notes, probably an optional argument is the best choice: `\keyboard[<options>]{<notes-right hand>}[<notes-left-hand>]`. The number of notes is arbitrary, but a problem would arise for “the same note with both hands”.

Comment: @egreg About notation. Yes, its indeed german. It so happens a lot of musicology is based on german methodology and i believe it important to conform to conventions, but as you say, its easy to modify to ones taste. There are alternatives though that are just as good, like {C1,Ciss2}, defing octaves very clearly. The {Ct} alternative is not an option, in my opinion. The left/right thing could be a problem, I see that. Is it an idea to "simply" stack the circles that collide?

Comment: @Buschmann That stacking requires some thought, because one has to track the already used keys. Can you please add to your question the “official” names in German and English?

Comment: @egreg Perhaps programing tracking is more work then reward? Best idea so far is to stack them, since you only have vertical space. About names. As you said, the "german" way of using ' apostrophes might not be the best sollution. In this scenario I believe {C1,C2} to be the most self explainitory; after 1 comes 2, hence two octaves. Another thought: How hard would it be to move the Root? Now the root is C, but for some cases I forsee a need to have a different Root, like E, i.e. the bottom note being E then follows two octaves from E1 to Diss2.

Comment: @Buschmann No, sorry, that's completely outside my plans. It would require complete reworking and I'm not going to try it. About the names: I *don't* know the complete list. Please, add it to your question.

Comment: @egreg Fair enough! As far as the list. -iss for sharps and ess for flats. In the ideal world one would have the possibillity to write both Dess or Ciss, resulting in the same note: *pc1*. However, if that is tedious work from a programers perspective i suggest working with either sharps or flats consequently. Ergo, sharps: C, Ciss, Diss, E, F, Fiss, G, Giss, A, Aiss, B. Flats: C, Dess, D, Ess, F, Gess, G, Ass, A, Bess, B.